# Problems running python in powershell terminal

Tags: python, powershell, terminal

I am an absolute beginner in programming and have started learning python
using the *learnpythonthehardway* book.
Now, when I type python in the powershell terminal I get
the message saying python is not recognized.

I typed the command given by zedshaw , this one :

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27", "User")
```

and I still get the same not recognized message.

My python27 is installed in `D:` drive
and even my windows is in `D:` drive.
Just wanted to inform you guys,
maybe you would need this info.

So, what do I do now?

Comment: A simpler/cleaner way to append to your path variable... $env:Path += ';C:\Python27'

Answer (score 2):

You said:

> I typed the command given by zedshaw , this one : >[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27", "User")

But then:

> My python27 is installed in d drive...

So wich is it? you should update the command to:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;D:\Python27", "User")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this bit of documentation:
http://docs.python.org/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables

Comment: So, the variable here is python
and the path is where python27.exe is located right?

Comment: You are giving windows a directory where it can look for executables. The environment variable for this is Path. By adding C:\Python27 to the Path environment variable you are informing windows that executables are in C:\Python27. python27.exe is located here.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)

Comment: Ah! I did that and it worked. Thanks

Comment: $env:PYTHONPATH = 'C:\My_python_lib'